# How can I use a pre-trained CNN for feature extraction with 4-channel images as input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have a dataset containing 4-channel multi-modal images (Visual + Infrared, or RGB-IR). I want to use a pretrained CNN for feature extraction. I will then use the extracted features for downstream processing - dimensionality reduction and clustering.

The problem is that for all models I find the weights have been obtained by training on the ImageNet dataset, which contains RGB images. I can't use one of those models for feature extraction because their input layer expects an input of shape (batch_size, height, width, 3) or (64, 224, 224, 3). In my case, my input is (64, 224, 224, 4).

Is there any way that I can use one of the pre-trained CNN models?

I have considered modifying the weights of the first layer of the base model. I've also considered maybe splitting the images into 3-channel (RGB) and 1-channel (IR) and performing feature extraction on them separately [processing the 1-channel IR as you would process grayscale images], and then concatenating the extracted features. Are either of these approaches correct? Is there are better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I take ResNet-18 as an example.

Now we first see the architecture of the ResNet in Pytorch.

[image]

The first layer of the input layer with the input channel = 3.

Therefore, we can first load the pre-trained CNN mdoel, and then modify the input layer with input channel = 4.

```
model = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=true)
model.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(4, 64, kernel_size=7, stride=2, padding=3, bias=False)
```